# AWS EKS in existing VPC context timeouts EBS CSI driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl, aws-ebs-csi-driver

I'm using eksctl to create an eks cluster

```yaml
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: xxx-dev
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.27"

vpc:
  id: vpc-xxx
  subnets:
    private:
      xxx-dev-private-a:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-private-b:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-private-c:
        id: subnet-xxx
    public:
      xxx-dev-public-a:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-public-b:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-public-c:
        id: subnet-xxx

nodeGroups:
  - name: dev-ng-postgres
    privateNetworking: true
    instanceType: t3.xlarge
    desiredCapacity: 3
```

```
eksctl create cluster -f eks/eks-cluster.yaml

export cluster_name=xxx-dev
oidc_id=$(aws eks describe-cluster --name $cluster_name --query "cluster.identity.oidc.issuer" --output text | cut -d '/' -f 5)
aws iam list-open-id-connect-providers | grep $oidc_id | cut -d "/" -f4
eksctl utils associate-iam-oidc-provider --cluster $cluster_name --approve

eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
    --name ebs-csi-controller-sa \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --cluster xxx-dev \
    --role-name AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole \
    --role-only \
    --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy \
    --approve
eksctl create addon --name aws-ebs-csi-driver --cluster xxx-dev --service-account-role-arn arn:aws:iam::account_id:role/AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole --force
```

I'm running this to init the cluster.

I still get context timeout errors when attempting to create ebs volumes. I believe the issue is from my existing VPCs. What are some things to check for to see what is blocking the requests?

I'm using eksctl to create an eks cluster

```yaml
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: xxx-dev
  region: us-east-1
  version: "1.27"

vpc:
  id: vpc-xxx
  subnets:
    private:
      xxx-dev-private-a:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-private-b:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-private-c:
        id: subnet-xxx
    public:
      xxx-dev-public-a:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-public-b:
        id: subnet-xxx
      xxx-dev-public-c:
        id: subnet-xxx

nodeGroups:
  - name: dev-ng-postgres
    privateNetworking: true
    instanceType: t3.xlarge
    desiredCapacity: 3
```

```
eksctl create cluster -f eks/eks-cluster.yaml

export cluster_name=xxx-dev
oidc_id=$(aws eks describe-cluster --name $cluster_name --query "cluster.identity.oidc.issuer" --output text | cut -d '/' -f 5)
aws iam list-open-id-connect-providers | grep $oidc_id | cut -d "/" -f4
eksctl utils associate-iam-oidc-provider --cluster $cluster_name --approve

eksctl create iamserviceaccount \
    --name ebs-csi-controller-sa \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --cluster xxx-dev \
    --role-name AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole \
    --role-only \
    --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy \
    --approve
eksctl create addon --name aws-ebs-csi-driver --cluster xxx-dev --service-account-role-arn arn:aws:iam::account_id:role/AmazonEKS_EBS_CSI_DriverRole --force
```

I'm running this to init the cluster.

I still get context timeout errors when attempting to create ebs volumes. I believe the issue is from my existing VPCs. What are some things to check for to see what is blocking the requests?

EDIT: when I have the VPC created I can create the EBS